# I am trying to use Recursion in this python program but it shows NameError. What should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        dic={}
        if n in dic:
            return dic.values
        elif n == 0 or n == 1:
            return 1
        elif n == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            a = climbStairs(n-1) + climbStairs(n-2)
            dict.update == dict.update({n:a})
            return a

b = Solution()
print(b.climbStairs(3))
```

This is the error:

> Line 11: NameError: name 'climbStairs' is not defined

Comment: When you're in a class you still have to reference the class. ie self.climbStairs(n-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@matt provided the answer to your concern above, but I want to point out several problems with your code.

```
dic={}
if n in dic:
    return dic.values
```

First of all, the `values` is the method of the dictionary, so it should be `dic.values()`. This method would return all values stored in the dictionary. However, you want to get specific value that corresponds to `n`. It should be `dic[n]`. Finally, you create an empty dictionary and then check if there is something in it? Of course, `n in dic` will be false at all times. You want to refer to some memory that is stored between recursions -- it makes sense to keep it on the instance (like `self.dic`)

```
dict.update == dict.update({n:a})
```

I am still wondering what this piece of code should be doing. It is a boolean comparison, so the right and left parts are being executed and compared... Why comparing?

The `update` is the method of the dictionary, so the LHS does not use it appropriately (no brackets) and even with brackets it implements nothing. The RHS keeps the dictionary the same, but for the key `n` assigns value `a`. Isn't it easier to write `dict[n]=a`.

Finally, the name of the object was `dic` before, and now it is `dict`.

I hope it helps. Good luck with learning.